# How to display sort indicator in the table header?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nssortdescriptor, nstablecolumn

I sorted the `NSTableColumn` using the `sort descriptors`. I used the following code for `Sorting`.

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Column3" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors= [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
        [self.dataArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

[tableView setIndicatorImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"NSAscendingSortIndicator"]
                          inTableColumn:[tableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"Column3"]];
```

I am able to get the image from `[NSImage imageNamed:@"NSAscendingSortIndicator"]`,but Iam not able to view the image in the tableview header.

Is there any way to simulate the `mouse click` on the `table column` to get that `Sort indicator`(up or down arrow in the table header) in the `table column`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Code will update the Sort indicator with out clicking on the header.

```
[self.tableView setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```